# Greasemonkey XHR not showing in firefox network devtools

Tags: javascript, firefox-developer-tools, greasemonkey-4, firefox-57+

I wrote a script as a user script and ran it on a specific website with Greasemonkey.

It worked perfectly, but I want to see requests that my script has sent
in the Firefox developer tools network tab. Currently it shows the page's requests and not my script's requests.

What should I do?

Comment: What version of Firefox? What version of Greasemonkey?

Comment: @brock-adams Firefox 57, Greasemonkey 4

Comment: I suspect that FF 57 does not have this capability; they broke so much...  You can try debugging your script on a Chromium based browser (and Tampermonkey).

Comment: @brock-adams Thanks, is it possible to send requests with XMLHttpRequest ,like original page requests ? to show requests in developer tools?

Comment: It's possible in Chrome, but was always tricky in FF.  With FF 57, I'm not even going to check.

Comment: Ok, I inject the user script to the main page (with Greasemonkey), and now shows the user script requests in the Developer tools like page originally requests,Thanks

Comment: Yes, but you won't be able to do cross-domain xhr, nor use GM functions that way.  But I guess you don't need such (yet).

Comment: I'm having the same issue with TamperMonkey in Chrome :\

Answer (score 3):

You need to open Browser Toolbox to see XMLHttpRequest of Greasemonkey.

See [how to enable and open Browser Toolbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Toolbox).

(Check "Enable browser chrome and add-on debugging toolboxes" and "Enable remote debugging" in [Developer Tools Settings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Settings))

You can find any XMLHttpRequest in the network monitor under Browser Toolbox.